# Composer package install warning in command line

Tags: command-line, composer-php, installation

I tried to install a package from here: 
`https://iwader.co.uk/post/tymon-jwt-auth-with-lumen-5-2`

So, I try to run this command:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:"^1.0@dev"
```

But I got this error:

```
The requested package tymon/jwt-auth: could not be found, it looks like its name is invalid,
 ":" is not allowed in package names.
```

May you have experience to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try quoting the entire name + version string when using the `require` command:

```
composer require "tymon/jwt-auth:^1.0@dev"
```